# 3D models giving performance issues, SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am creating some .dae models for my game. The game adds them to screen in this way:

```
func addPine(gridPosition: SCNVector3, levelNode: SCNNode){
    let carScene = SCNScene(named: "assets.scnassets/Models/car.dae")

    // Create a material using the model_texture.tga image
    let carMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    carMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "assets.scnassets/Textures/model_texture.tga")
    carMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = false

    // Create a clone of the Car node of the carScene - you need a clone because you need to add many cars
    let carNode = carScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Car", recursively: false)!.clone() as SCNNode
    carNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.3, 0.3,  randomBetweenNumbers(0.8, secondNum: 2.2))
    carNode.name = "Car"
    carNode.position = gridPosition

    // Set the material
    carNode.geometry!.firstMaterial = carMaterial

    // Create a physicsbody for collision detection
    let carPhysicsBodyShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.30, height: 0.20, length: 0.16, chamferRadius: 0.0), options: nil)

    carNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Kinematic, shape: carPhysicsBodyShape)
    carNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Car
    carNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player

    levelNode.addChildNode(carNode)
}
```

If I use this method with certain .dae models, the game runs at 60fps. Instead, if I use this code with other .dae files, the game runs slower, at 35-40fps, and if I add too many of these objects, the app crashes giving a memory fault. The .dae files are exactly the same. Furthermore the Bounding Box Size is the same, so the size of the actual model appears to be the same. The only difference I notice is in the number of Vertices and Polygons. In the more complex model the two are 15300 and 5000 respectively. The simple .dae file has is 2000 and 930. Does this have a memory impact? (given that the objects are around the same size) (p.s. The models are done in Blender)

Comment: The number of polygons will, of course, have an impact.  How many models of 15300/5000 are you attempting to display, as that isn't *that* many for modern mobile hardware?

Comment: 11/12 per time on the screen. As the user moves his character forward more are created. They are trees, or other objects of the landscape

Comment: Then the number of polygons are certainly the issue.

Comment: Well polygons are defined by vertices, so it's basically the same thing.

Comment: What were the results of the optimizations I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569551/modify-the-bounding-box-size-of-3d-model?

Comment: I tried using SCNLevelOfDetail, and the performance did improve. However I finally managed to reduced the polygon number on Blender and that solved the issue.